# "No resource found" errors Android gradle build for files in .gradle/caches

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

My Gradle build on Android Studio fails with multiple errors such as.

```
C:\Users\%USER_HOME%\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar\67e074a850e794c5187b156467264a93\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml

Error:(26, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material').
```

The project is an exercise code of Udacity Android course. I have no changes of my own. It compiles fine when others try.

Anyone seen the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting these errors because the project name was very long, and the location I was saving the project in, added to it. That apparently caused some files to be missing. Moving the project to another location so that the file names are not crossing the system limit resolved the errors for me.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Delete your build cache and then rebuild your project i.e,

- Delete the build folder inside your app `directory`
- Rebuild your project and then try again

Comment: Thank you. That didn't fix the issues.

Comment: this doesn't help